# elasticSearch get data from two indices in one object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have index ***users*** and ***posts***.
In post index I have user_id parameter, and when I search post in ***posts*** index using user_id, I should get this post and user data full in one object.
How I can send search query in two indices ?

Comment: Don't think it is possible. You would require that to be managed at your `application/service` layer or denormalize the data in such a way that you'd have `single index`, querying which would display all the required information. Other alternatives would be to make use of `nested` datatype. Refer to this link for more info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

Comment: Kamal, thanks for answer. And can you give one example in my case of this nested datatype ? I have very little time for this

Comment: I've posted an answer below, Marat. Hope it would help!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the multi search feature: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

The response is a array of the search response and status for each search request preserving the order of the multi search request

Answer (score 0):

I have created the below data models as a sample. My index would have data model in the below format.

```
Posts:
 - post_id
 - title
 - description
 * comments
   - user_id
   - firstname
   - comment

* - meaning multiple values
```

Basically what I am doing is saving **all the data** of a single post in a *single document*.

### Sample Mapping

```
PUT post
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "comments":{  
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{  
                  "userid":{  
                     "type":"text"
                  },
                  "firstname":{  
                     "type":"text"
                  },
                  "comment":{  
                     "type":"text"
                  }
               }
            },
            "post_id":{  
               "type":"text"
            },
            "post_description":{  
               "type":"text"
            },
            "post_title":{  
               "type":"text"
            },
            "owner":{  
               "type":"text"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Document

```
POST post/mydocs/1
{
  "post_id": "1",
  "owner": "1",
  "post_description": "I'm doing some analysis on this and its very confusing. Can anyone help me here?",
  "post_title": "neo4j vs elasticsearch",
  "comments": [
    {
      "userid": "2",
      "firstname": "John",
      "comment": "Both are totally different here"
    },
    {
      "userid": "3",
      "firstname": "Jack",
      "comment": "Depends on the user case, doesn't it. "
    }
  ]

}
```

### Sample Query

```
POST post/_search
{  
   "_source":[  
      "post_id",
      "comments.userid",
      "comments.firstname"
   ],
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match_all":{}  // you can put any condition here 
            },
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"comments",
                  "query":{  
                     "match":{  
                        "comments.userid":"2"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Well it may not be perfect and might looks vague/amusing, however I hope this would help you in your understanding.

Infact you can actually check stackoverflow's data model(entity called **POST**) and their elasticsearch implementation. Refer to this [LINK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) to see how they've modeled their `post` in their rdbms database and this [LINK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187501/412539) to see how they've created index for the very same table.

I'm really hoping this helps :)